# How can we start writing text from center

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to achieve the layout shown in Screenshot. My Aim is to start writing text from center. (In general in flutter we can write from left to right or right to left and we can also center the text but when line breaks it start writing from left so rather than manually center the text I want to know the method which writes in center i.e Just like we type in MS word when we centered the text)

[image: Question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **RichText** widget. Here's an example:

```
RichText(
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  text: TextSpan(
    text:  "By signing up you're agreeing to our\n",
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text:'Terms of Service',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            showDialog<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return TermsOfServicePage();
              },
            );
          },
      ),
      TextSpan(
          text:  '  and  ',
          style: TextStyle(
          )),
      TextSpan(
        text: "Privacy Policy",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTap = () {
            showDialog<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return PrivacyPolicyPage();
              },
            );
            },
        )
      ],
  ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small container, inside that container you can add a column, in that column add a row, in first row you can add Text('By signing...'), TextButton('Terms & cond...') your text color will be blue, background color white, keep padding to minimum.

Add second row in you column and do the exact thing you did in the first row